# How can I update value of array in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am retriving following data from the database.When I do `print_r`, it gives me follwing result.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [params] => {"size":"980|*|485|*|1","responsive":"1|*|0","align":"normal","autoplay":"1|*|6000" } ) )
```

Now I want to change the value of **autoplay**(which is last in this array) in it.How can I do that with the `update` query ?

NOTE: Field name is `param` in database and table name is xyz.

Comment: Question: What have you tried?

Comment: Because `json_decode($array[0]->params)` would get you the object that would allow you to modify it.

Comment: Actually I am totally newbie so I don't have any Idea how can I even start.If any help from you would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, your `params` is a json object. You need to decode that object so that you can use it.

```
$data = json_decode($item[0]->params);

$data->autoplay = 'New VALUE';
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/216390)

Comment: It worked like charm :)
But can you tell me how can I update it in Database also ??
Will it be done by simple query like
`Update $tablename SET autoplay = $data->autoplay` ??

Comment: I have tried thi query `$myupdate = "update wp_nextend_smartslider_sliders set params = $data where id='3'";` but it gives me this error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in`
How can I pass string to this ?

Comment: `$myupdate = "update wp_nextend_smartslider_sliders set params = '".json_encode($data)."' where id='3'";` would probably work.